# PHP CSV Export Issue

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export MySQL data to CSV file. It works fine on all browsers, but having issue only on MAC system. The file gets downloaded as filename.csv.xls which should be filename.csv I have tried all possible solutions but nothing seems to work. am I missing something here? Below is the source code.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
header("Content-Disposition:csv" . date("Y-m-d")); 
header( "Content-disposition: filename="file.csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: How about shortening that to just the relevant information for the question being asked?

Comment: FYI, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be your content-type header. Try this instead:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
```

A security note:
I also noticed you are open to SQL injection. You should always pass your variables through [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) especially since you are not even sanitizing the data. You are also using mysql instead of the *improved* mysqli.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I will ask my developer to review the security issues. I tried changing content type as text/csv, but when I try to export it just shows entire data in the web page itself.

Comment: That's actually normal. You will need to improve the script to do a forced download at that point. There are numerous ways to do that. You typically leave the option to download up to the user. It's just as easy to right-click on the link and select "save link as". Of course you could also just save the page (it will save as a csv).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you used the correct content type in the headers

```
text/csv
```

rather than the Excel .xls content type header

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```